# Help to Prove Convex Quadrilateral Problem

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

I'd appreciate help with solving this convex quadrilateral riddle. It appears to hold true in all of my test cases, but I'm not sure how I would go about writing a proof for it.

> Let $UVWX$ be a convex quadrilateral. 
>   Let $Y$ be the midpoint of $UW$, 
>   and let $Z$ be the midpoint of $VX$. 
>   Show that $|UV| + |VW| +  |WX| + |XU| \geq |UW| + |VX| + 2|YZ|$ 
>   where $|UV|$ denotes the distance from $U$ to $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $UVWX$ is convex, all its interior angles are $\le 180^\circ$.

Also
$\text{"Z is midpoint of VY"} \implies 2|YZ| = |VY| \tag{1}$

We have the following:

- $\angle{UVX} \le \angle{UVW}$ with equality only if $V,X,W$ are collinear
- $\angle{UVW} \le 180^\circ$ with equality only if $U,V,W$ are collinear.

So $\angle{UVX} < 180^\circ$ unless $U,V,W,X$ are collinear. Such a shape is not a quadrilateral.

Thus we can draw a point $T$ such that $UVXT$ is a parallelogram. Then it follows by similar triangles that $VY$ lies on the diagonal and $|VT| = 2|VY|$. By the triangle inequality applied to $\Delta{VUT}$ we have:

$|VT| \le |VU| + |UT|$ which can be rearranged to $|VT| \le |UV| + |VX|$

Hence
$2|VY| \le |UV| + |VX| \tag{2}$

Therefore, it would be sufficient to prove

$|UV| + |VW| +  |WX| + |XU| \ge |UW| + |VX| + \frac{1}{2}(|UV| + |VX|)$

or equivalently

$\frac{1}{2}|UV| + |VW| +  |WX| + |XU| \ge |UW| + \frac{3}{2}|VX| \tag{3}$

But this **fails** in the case of a unit square where $|UV| = |VW| = |WX| = |XU| = 1, |UW| = |VX| = \sqrt2$ because $3.5 < 2.5 \sqrt2$.

So using this approach, we are at an impasse. Asymmetry considerations alone would make me suspicious of (3) and even of the original inequality to be proved.

Comment: This is such a great answer, but I messed up copying the original inequality, as you noticed. Maybe rethink the part for where Z is the midpoint of VX, in a new answer or something? +1 also

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback. I will have another look - the problem is a bit harder now, though.

Comment: Hmm extreme cases hold true, but how would we prove the cases in-between?